# AngularJS : directives which take a template through a configuration object, and show that template multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-compile

I'm looking to create a custom directive that will take a template as a property of a configuration object, and show that template a given number of times surrounded by a header and footer. What's the best approach to create such a directive?

The directive would receive the configuration object as a scope option:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      config: '=?'
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

This object (called config) is passed optionally to the directive using two way binding, as show in the code above. The configuration object can include a template and a number indicating the number of times the directive should show the template. Consider, for example, the following config object:

```
var config = {
  times: 3,
  template: '<div>my template</div>'
};
```

It would, when passed to the directive, cause the directive to show the template five times (using an ng-repeat.) The directive also shows a header and a footer above and below the template(s):

```
<div>the header</div>
<div>my template</div>
<div>my template</div>
<div>my template</div>
<div>the footer</div>
```

What's the best way to implement this directive? Note: When you reply, please provide a working example in a code playground such as Plunker, as I've run into problems with each possible implementation I've explored.

**Update**, the solutions I've explored include:

1. The use of the directive's link function to append the head, template with ng-repeat, and footer. This suffers from the problem of the template not being repeated, for some unknown reason, and the whole solutions seems like a hack.
2. The insertion of the template from the configuration object into middle of the template of the directive itself. This proves difficult because jqLite seems to have removed all notion of a CSS selector from its jQuery-based API, leading me to wonder if this solution is "the Angular way."
3. The use of the compile function to build out the template. This seems right to me, but I don't know if it will work.

Comment: You should probably include each possible implementation you have explored in your question.

Comment: @DTing Each of the possible implementations I explored has now been described.

Comment: Could there be Angular directives/expressions in the template? Will the config object and the contained template change and need to be watched for changes? Is there a reason why the template is defined inside the object to begin with as opposed to within the View?

Comment: Those are great questions. How would the solution be different if there were Angular directives/expressions in the template? Also, how would the solution be different if the template within the config object needed to be watched for changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could indeed use `ng-repeat` but within your directive template rather than manually in the link (as that wouldn't be compiled, hence not repeated).

One question you didn't answer is, should this repeated template be compiled and linked by Angular, or is it going to be static HTML only?

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        config: '=?'
      },
      templateUrl: 'myTemplate',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.array = new Array(config.times);
      }
    }
  }
```

With `myTemplate` being:

```
<header>...</header>
<div ng-repeat="item in array" ng-bind-html="config.template"></div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Comment: This solution works great for static templates which contain only HTML. How would the solution be different if there were Angular directives / expressions in the template? Also, how would the solution be different if the template within the config object needed to be watched for changes?

Comment: If the expression contains expression you cannot avoid to compile it. You can use that directive for instance: https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile. About the changes you have nothing to do: as soon as config.template is updated the new template would be reflected on the DOM (since ng-bind-html is already a watcher)

Answer (score 0):

I'd think to use `ng-transclude` in this case, because the header & footer wrapper will be provided by the directive the inner content should change on basis of condition.

**Markup**

```
<my-directive>
  <div ng-repeat="item in ['1','2','3']" ng-bind-html="config.template| trustedhtml"><div>
</my-directive>
```

**Directive**

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.directive('myDirective', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>the header</div>'+
                 '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'+
              '<div>the footer</div>',
    scope: {
      config: '=?'
    }
    .....
  }
}
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('trustedhtml', function($sce){
   return function(val){
      return $sce.trustedHtml(val);
   }
})
```

Comment: This approach is rather awkward. The directive "pollutes" the parent's scope with the declaration of `trustedHtml`, and if you use `scope: true` or `scope: {}` then the `ng-transclude` approach would not work

Comment: @NewDev thanks for heads up..but why it won't work with isolated scope?

Comment: because the transcluded scope would inherit from the parent - and so `trustedHtml` function would not be visible to it

Comment: @NewDev i moved it to filter..does it looks fine or still there is any issue with the code? what you think..Thanks for you response & time